# SVN, Samba and Symbolic Links. How to get them all to play together?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, samba, symlink

I've got a website project under version control that relies on files from an unversioned directory on the same server via Symbolic Links.

I'm currently storing the symbolic links in the repository. The idea is that if someone checks out a working copy on to the same server they can edit and test the working copy of the project before committing it back to the repository.

When they checkout their working copy it successfully sets up the symlinks so that the entire site works when testing.

The users that work on the project are Windows users, so I've set a samba shares on the server and then mapped them to network drives in Windows. People can edit their working copies directly on the server via network shares and then test them in the web browser before committing their changes back to the repository via TortoiseSVN.

**The Problem**

The problem I have is that Samba resolves the symlinks as expected but when a user tries to commit their changes back to the repository, TortoiseSVN thinks the linked files are part of the project and tries to commit the target files to the repository and not the symlinks themselves.

I tried turning off symlink support in samba which means that the linked files cannot be resolved as I don't really want people to have access to the linked files nor do I want to import the linked files in the repository. The problem with this is that I get `Can't stat '\\webserver\projects\working\project\symlinked_file.php'. Access is denied`

Apart from the symlink problem everything else works 100% perfectly. Users can either checkout website projects to their machine and work on them (but can't test) or checkout them out to their space on the dev web server and work on them and fully test. So I don't want to change the workflow process, I just need a solution to the symbolic link issue.

Many thanks.

Comment: Problem for ServerFault.com or SuperUser.com?

Comment: There are 4054 tags for SVN on StackOverflow. On ServerFault it's 217. So I think I'm more likely to get a response regarding SVN issues here on StackOverflow.

Comment: Might be an oldie, but the question is still a valid one I'd like there to be a better answer for then 'just don't use symlinks' (if there is one. Bounty time :).

Comment: And yes, samba+subversion+symlinks is still empty on serverfault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to remove the symbolic links from the repository. I then created a bash script that prompts the user to create the symlinks in their working copy. I had to make sure I turned off Samba's `follow symlinks` option to stop TortoiseSVN from attempting to add the linked files to the repository.

Also it should be noted that when the user performs a commit using TortoiseSVN, that it will show the links in the changes log but they will not be checked and therefore will not be added to the repository. You just need to ignore them.

Answer (score 1):

Could you use UNIX symlinks alongside [NTFS symlinks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS_symbolic_link) to maintain compatibility with windows? Or, you could always version the other files and use [svn:externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.externals.html) to link to them.

Comment: NTFS symlinks will resolve to local filesystems as far as I know, which is difficult to keep in sync in mixed Linux vs. Windows environment. Also, ideally symlinks would be in SVN, so automatically created on checkout/update, which afaik no Windows SVN client supports a.t.m, or am I wrong? Versioning the other files & using externals can be a proper solution for code (but mostly you just want a single checkout of that code in production, not multiple locations as externals in different exports/checkouts.

Comment: Also, a major reason not to version some files/dirs is that they for instance either large binaries which shouldn't be under version control (think for instance a profile pictures directory for a webproject), or contain highly volatile constantly changing data with a limited lifespan, which is needed / expected for running an application, but is not part of the code of the application.

Comment: I hear you. We've run into a lot of situations where versioning certain files just isn't a good idea. Normally, we just put them into our maven repository and have them pulled in by maven as resources. Also, for files that change a lot, we've stored them on an NFS share (which windows and unix can mount) and just had maven pull them in. This second option could be done with any build tool.

Comment: Hmm, a build tool would work, but seeing as how hard I had to fight to even make them use version control et al... A correct answer, but not one I can see me implementing very soon (we can always dream... might get there after a few months carefull nudging).

Answer (score 0):

Aight, after going trough several options, this is what I ended up with: The problem is that Windows does not know about symlinks, but neither does Tortoise destroy them on Windows checkouts. The solution is then to let people do the checkouts on the Windows share themselves, and after that, find a way to add the symlinks back in.

Of course, just overwriting them is not an option, as Tortoise will complain about changed files/dirs etc. We want to leave them alone. For a webserver with static images/other resources in a symlinked dir a simple `Alias` in Apache configuration would work, but alas, our codebase also includes code by symlink.

Under debian, `unionfs-fuse` solved those troubles. The recipe that seems to work here:

- Create base checkouts somewhere on the linux server (svnroots).
- Create a dir where we are going to create an 'overlay' (carcass).
- Search the svn-checkouts dir for symlinks, and recreate them in the carcass:

.

```
for file in `find $DEVPATH/svnroots/ -type l`;do
       path=`dirname $file | sed "s,$DEVPATH/svnroots,$DEVPATH/carcass,g"`
       mkdir -p $path
       path=$path/`basename $file`;
       ln -s `readlink $file` $path;
done
```

- Create the desired directories (with peoples files from their share, but the symlinks as stored in subversion:

.

```
for user in ${windowsusers[@]};
    unionfs-fuse -o cow,allow_other,suid,uid=33,gid=33 $DEVPATH/carcass=ro:$DEVPATH/$user/=rw $DEVPATH/correct_dirs/$user
done
```

Reading/writing on that directory will go to the users directory, the carcass dir is read-only but is overlayed on the users directory, resulting in correct symlinks. The scripts are easy enough to rerun on symlink-changes in subversion (and a remount is not needed: changes in carcass are directly reflected in the correct_dirs).